# I need to do something after paste，how to do that?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I want to make something like below image with custom Keyboard extension,

[image]

[image: Custom Keyboard]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of your TextField

```
class CustomTexrtField: UITextField {
   //will see implementation later
}
```

Now simply override paste function inside it :)

```
override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
        super.paste(sender)
        //do whatever you want to do here after paste
        print("me here")
    }
```

Hope it helps